# get image from folder outside yii

Tags: image, yii

**EDIT**

My `htdocs/myprojectyii` folder is in `C` drive, So can I get image from folder in `E` drive?
I edit my coding to this

```
<?php $path = 'file:///E:/image/myimage.jpg'?>
<img src="<?php echo $path ?>" width="100" height="100"/>
```

if i click path on `src` image (firebug), path is right(cause it display image) but in mypage, image not display

Comment: If you edit your question so that it reverse everything, please write an `EDIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mostafa Shahverdy and @Kalpesh Patel thank you so much for your supports..
but finally i got solution to use base64_encode, like this

```
$path = 'E:/images/myimage.jpg'

    if($fp = fopen($path,"rb", 0)) //open file
    { 
        $path = fread($fp,filesize($path)); //read file
        fclose($fp); 
        $path = chunk_split(base64_encode($path)); //encode image to base64
        $encode = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $path .'"  width="200" height="200">'; 
        echo $encode; //show image
    }
```

so i can access image in local drive :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must try `file:///E:/images/myimage.jpg` instead of only `E:/image/myimage.jpg`. Second this won't work :D because [That's a security feature .. it isn't possible in any browser on any platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982585/655316).

Comment: hmm i'll try it..yes, cause all file image must be in local drive

Comment: your answer is correct, but it not show image even the path is right

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg
Please refer this

Comment: @YessieSetiawan, first open images in a separate tab/window to make sure that you are typing correct path. Even you can go to `File`>`Open` with your browser to find the path

Comment: @RohitSubedi: what kind of extension?add-on on firefox?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy my path is correct because i can see the image when i click path in firebug, but image not appear in my webpage

Comment: @YessieSetiawan, Try loading image from `http` (for example `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png`) to see if you can see any images in your page at all!

Comment: I'm sorry to give you the wrong hint first time I answered. I didn't test it myself at the begin. I updated my answer now. and also this is a duplicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

For better security yii not allow direct but you can use php function to get images

see in yii controller names UploadController.php add function

```
function actiongetBusinessProfilePic($dir='',$fileName='')
{
    $name = FILE_UPLOAD.'businessprofilepic/'.$dir.'/'.$fileName;
    $ext=$this->actiongetExt($fileName);
    if(file_exists($name))
    {
    $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');   
    header("Content-Type: image/".$ext);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
    fpassthru($fp);
    }
}
```

now in view page do sometihng like this

```
<img id="main_image_preview" src="<?php echo $base_path;?>upload/getBusinessProfilePic/dir/<?php echo $imageDir;?>/fileName/<?php echo $avatar;?>" alt="Upload Avatar" border="0" />
```